# Is there a way to conveniently edit protobuf without a schema?

Tags: encoding, protocol-buffers

I currently have to work with raw protobuf data and was wondering if there is a fast / convenient way to edit raw protobuf data?

As an example, the hex data `08 96 01 12 07 74 65 73 74 69 6e 67` [decodes](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Hex(%27Auto%27)Protobuf_Decode(%27%27,false,false)&input=MDggOTYgMDEgMTIgMDcgNzQgNjUgNzMgNzQgNjkgNmUgNjc) to:

```
{
    "1": 150,
    "2": "testing"
}
```

What if I want to edit the string "testing" in this case? I could manually edit the binary code, but I have to deal with huge structs which are nested, therefore I would look for a way to just edit the data directly.

I don't know the schema, therefore I can't use the "Protobuf Encode" module of CyberChef.

Do you know anything useful in this regards?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult and error-prone:

- Protobuf uses variable-length encoding, see [Base 128 varints](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/#varints).
- Changing nested messages can require changing the parent messages (turtles all the way up [sic.])
- Due to the way messages are encoded, disassembly can be ambiguous

Google has a tool [protoscope](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protoscope) that can be used to edit binary messages.